# Magento 2: Credit Memo refund amount in transactional email

Tags: transactional-mail, magento2.4.2, creditmemo, variables, refund

So, I have a custom email setup for credit memo and I am using **{{var creditmemo.grand_total}}** variable to display refunded amount in my transactional email. Everything is fine except I want to show two digits after decimal no matter what.
Right now its showing 2 digits after decimal but if the last digit is 0 then it won't display 0.
For example if the refunded amount is 29.90 then in the email it's showing 29.9 . I want it to show 29.90 .